# Difficulty connecting to MS SQL Server from Postgresql on Windows (using DBI-Link)

Tags: sql-server, windows, odbc, dbi, postgresql-9.3

Dear Stackoverflow Gurus,

I am having an issue connecting to MS SQL Server (2008) from PostgreSQL 9.3 on Windows. I am trying to connect through DBI-Link DBD::ODBC for Sql Server. 
I would like your help on how to solve this issue, or maybe point out another way to Communicate to SQL Server from PostgreSQL on Windows.

The drivers seem to be working because when I add wrong credentials I get:

```
Severity: ERROR, Code: XX000, Line: 2117, Position:  ErrorMessage: DBI
 connect('Driver={SQL
 Server};Server=10.XX.YY.ZZ\MyInstance','a_user',...) failed:
 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user
 'a_user'. (SQL-28000) at line 37. at line 35.
```

---

The Query I am using to create the connection (in Postgres) is:

```
UPDATE
    pg_catalog.pg_settings
SET
    setting =
        CASE WHEN 'dbi_link' = ANY(string_to_array(setting, ','))
        THEN setting
        ELSE 'dbi_link,' || setting
        END
WHERE
    name = 'search_path'
;
SELECT make_accessor_functions(
    'dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};Server=10.XX.YY.ZZ\MyInstance',
    'a_user',
    'Some_Password',
    '---
AutoCommit: 1
RaiseError: 1
',
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    'dbo'
);
```

The error I get (which also looks like it did connect) is:

```
Severity: ERROR, Code: XX000, Line: 2117, Position: 
ErrorMessage: Could not connect to database
data source: dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};Server=10.XX.YY.ZZ\MyInstance
user: a_user
password: Some_Password
dbh attributes:
---
AutoCommit: 1
RaiseError: 1


[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Changed database context to 'master'. (SQL-01000)
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Changed language setting to us_english. (SQL-01000) at line 35.
```

---

My System:

```
OS: Windows 7 64-bit
PostgreSQL: 9.3
Perl: Strawberry Perl 5.14.3
Python: 3.4
```

---

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the connection string is wrong.. see this [link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-10-0-odbc-driver/)

Comment: @Max
I have tried the following driver strings with same result though:
` - Driver={SQL Server}`
` - Driver={SQL Server Native Client}`
` - Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}`

Comment: Try to create the connection from control panel ODBC driver to see if work, try to see on Event Viewer if there are message or check the PostgreSQL error logging (if any)

Comment: Thanks for helping @Max. I have created a DSN and tested successfully. I have even used the DSN in the connection string instead: dbi:ODBC:DSN=myDSN - But it's still giving me the same error in Postgres

Comment: Check if the user running the postgresql service has permission to access the Sql Server, and check on event viewer

Comment: Hi @Max. Initially the service was run locally but I have now set it up to be run automatically by a user who has permission to SQL server. I nearly thought that's it! But unfortunately I am still getting the same issue. What baffles me is that although I get the message "Could not connect to Database", I get the response of a successful connection at the end: [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/143339)

Comment: You're trying to `UPDATE` the `pg_catalog.pg_settings` view? What the ... oh, that's cool. I didn't know you could `UPDATE pg_catalog.pg_settings` as an alternative to `set_config`.